Makefile - how to check for the existence of a file from within a rule?
Here is a snapshot fragment of the Makefile logic problem, extremely simplified:
Directory and file structure:
\--project
    |---Makefile
    \---sub-project
         |---Makefile

Contents of /project/Makefile:
QUIET       =   --no-print-directory
 
all:
    @make $(QUIET) -C sub-project
    @echo CONTENT OF sub-project/bin FOLDER:
    @ls sub-project/bin
ifeq ("$(wildcard sub-project/bin/afile)", "")
    @echo Missing 'afile' from 'sub-project/bin/'
else
    @echo SUCCESS!
endif
 
test:
    @echo TESTING - CONTENT OF sub-project/bin FOLDER:
    @ls sub-project/bin
ifeq ("$(wildcard sub-project/bin/afile)", "")
    @echo Missing 'afile' from 'sub-project/bin/'
else
    @echo SUCCESS!
endif
 
clean:
 
fclean:
    @make $(QUIET) -C sub-project fclean
 
re: fclean all
 
.PHONY: all clean fclean re

Contents of /project/sub-project/Makefile:
all:
    @mkdir -p bin
    @echo test file > bin/afile
 
clean:
 
fclean:
    @rm -rf bin
 
re: fclean all
 
.PHONY: all clean fclean re

The issue here is, if make is ran from within the /project folder, the
sub-project's Makefile is processed and the /project/sub-project/bin/afile
is created, which is then checked from the /project/Makefile, however, it
is undetected, although IT IS THERE.
IF THE make IS RAN THE SECOND TIME FROM WITHIN THE /project FOLDER, THE
EXPECTED RESULT IS ACHIEVED, BECAUSE THE FILE /project/sub-project/bin/afile
IS ALREADY THERE WHEN THE ifeq ("$(wildcard sub-project/bin/afile)", "") line
GETS EXECUTED FROM /project/Makefile
----- UPDATE BELOW, WITH A MORE CONCRETE EXAMPLE, ATTEMPTING TO USE make rules ONLY, IF EVER POSSIBLE ------------------------
Consider the following file/project structure, where sub-project1 and sub-project2 are two completely different projects, having their own Makefiles. And, the actual main project just uses them, so, it will need to call $(MAKE) -C sub-project1 and $(MAKE) -C sub-project2 at some point.
\--project
    |---Makefile
    \---sub-project1
    |    \---Makefile
    \---sub-project2
         \---Makefile

Now, let's consider, that 'project' will 1st look to see if sub-project2 is present and available and if so, it will compile it, create a project/bin folder and create a symbolic link there, pointing to the sub-project2/bin/executable-file.
ONLY IF sub-project2 is missing, will the main 'project' attempt to compile sub-project1 and basically, do the same, create a symbolic link to it's executable into the prohect/bin folder.
How could I attempt to do all this logic by only using rules in the project's Makefile?
Ex. Makefile:
 1: all: sub-project2/bin/executable-file msg_using_subp2 compile_subp2 | project/bin
 2:
 3: sub-project2/bin/executable-file: msg_using_subp1 compile_subp1 | project/bin
 4: # IF make REACHES HERE, IT MEANS THE above executable file
 5: # is missing, so, "proceed" to compile sub-project1 
 6:
 7: msg_subp1:
 8:     @echo Falling back to sub-project1.
 9:
10: compile_sp1:
11:     @make -C sub-project1
12:     ln -sf ../sub-project1/bin/execuutable-file bin/executable
13:     @echo "Sub-project1 successfully set!"
14: #   AND, THE MAKE SHOULD STOP HERE, HOWEVER, IT WILL JUMP BACK TO LINE 3 AND THEN
15: #   BACK TO LINE 1, AND WILL CONTINUE WITH msg_using_subp2 AND compile_subp2
16:
17: msg_subp2:
18: ...
19:
20: compile_subp2:
21:     ...

project/bin:
    @mkdir -p project/bin

As in the above comments within the 'compile_sp1' rule, the make will keep going. I would like to stop it there, without any errors, and I understood that is not possible? (I have managed to use a one, LONG line shell script, broken up into many lines by using ';' and '', however, I am just attempting to see if there is a 'neat' make only way?)

Have you considered doing the job in a way that is more idiomatic for make, instead?  Non-recursive make would be the gold standard here: one makefile (possibly an aggregate created via include) would be responsible for the whole build, and if it failed to build afile on some run then it would know.

Alternatively, you need to be able to trust make and all your makefiles. Supposing, then, that the only way that the subproject make fails to ensure that afile is built is if it fails with an error, you can rely on detecting such an error via make's exit status.  This is better than just testing for the file's presence, because you will catch cases when the file is present, but was not brought up to date because of the subproject make failing.

The problem is that preprocessor statements like ifeq etc. are parsed as the makefile is read in, which happens before any actual targets are considered or built.  At the time the makefile is read in, the afile file doesn't exist.  It only exists AFTER make has invoked all the prerequisites of that target.
If you want the recipe to test whether a file exists or not, you must put the test into the recipe (that is, it must be indented by a TAB character so it's part of the recipe, not part of the global makefile).  However, you cannot use preprocessor statements like ifeq as part of a recipe, because recipes are sent to the shell and must be valid shell syntax, not make syntax.
So you have to test for existence using shell constructs, not make constructs.  Like this:
all:
        @make $(QUIET) -C sub-project
        @echo CONTENT OF sub-project/bin FOLDER:
        @ls sub-project/bin
        if test -f sub-project/bin/afile; then \
            echo SUCCESS; \
        else \
            echo Missing 'afile' from 'sub-project/bin/'; \
        fi

Of course there are other ways to implement the test.  But it has to be part of the recipe, you can't use make preprocessor statements for it.
Nit: You should always use $(MAKE) to invoke a sub-make, never plain make.

Thank you for your reply @MadScientist All you described makes perfect sense. This means, I will have to delegate the decision making to a shell script and take it out of the Makefile. The way you rewrote the if statement is good, however, I would need to do other steps beside only the echo message :)

Well, of course you don't HAVE to use a shell script.  If it was in the makefile before it can be kept in the makefile afterward.  But you will have to get the semicolons and backslashes correct to put it into the recipe, that's true.

Instead of testing for the existence of a file, you could instead operate on the lack of a target file. Think about it: make and Makefile rules are all about executing code in reaction to certain prerequisites – the existence of target files – if those are not met. So you could define a target rule that springs into action, if a specific file is missing. For example you could use eval to change the content of a variable:
.PHONY: all

TEST_AFILE ?= 1
all: sub-project/bin/afile
    @echo $(TEST_AFILE)

sub-project/bin/afile:
    @echo "$@ missing"
    $(eval TEST_AFILE := 0)


Very good point here, thank you! Your insight engages my mind :)

I have updated my original description, to incorporate a sample, trying to only use make rules? Any suggestions, perhaps? :)

@Atti: The recursion trouble you're running into stems from the fact that a sub-make will be an independent instance with zero implicit insight into the state of a superior make process. You must pass in the super state to the sub-make through variables. Which is, why I make my example setting a variable. However for this to work with sub-makes you want the top level init using the ?= syntax.
